# Trait is working oddly Laravel ORM

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I have next trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait LastElement {
    public function scopeLast($query)
    {
        return $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                     ->first();
    }
}
```

As you can see it's simple Laravel's scope. It's working like `first()`, but returning the last element.

I have next model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\LastElement;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Daemon extends Model
{
    use LastElement;

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];

    protected static function check()
    {
        $last = self::last();

        if (!empty($last)) {
            sleep(1);

            return empty(self::where('id', $last->id)
                             ->where('updated_at', $last->updated_at)
                             ->first());
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static function start()
    {
        if (self::check()) {
            $me = new self;
            $me->save();

            $i = 0;

            while (true) {
                $i++;

                usleep(1 / 3 * 1000);

                if (($i % 3) == 0) {
                    $i = 0;
                    $me->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's no matter what this model do - but in `check()` method my `$last` var is the instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. In my other model this trait working good - what do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Scope should return a Builder instance because it meant to be chain-able. In other words scope should never execute the query.

Now in your case IMHO you don't need a trait for this. Just use built in scope [`latest()`](https://github.com/pmatseykanets/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1138):

```php
protected static function check()
{
    ...
    $last = self::lastest('id')->first();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I want to create something like `first()` so I used trait. But I don't understand why in another models this trait is working good, but in this model not.